# xterm no longer starting as root user on RHEL6

Tags: ssh, x11

I am totally stuck even after reading both [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108679/x-client-forwarded-over-ssh-cannot-open-display-localhost11-0) (if it isn't already obvious I don't have much experience with Linux.)

I am trying to install `WebSphere 8.5` on `RHEL6`. Everything was going fine with the Installation Manager GUI, then after `IBMHTTPServer`, `Web Server Plugin`, and `WebSphere Customization Toolbox`, I was unable to start the installation manager.

Searching the internet let me to believe that testing if even `xterm` worked would be a good idea and unfortunately it does not.

```
# whoami
root
# xterm
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: %s
```

I am connected to the Linux box using `mobaXterm` and the xterm command works fine on a cloned VM via the same connection.

```
# echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
# xauth list
ap01/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  7f20dc9e52baff302a442c46bbd4869b
```

Again, I am new to this so may not be understanding what is relevant, please let me know if I can post further information.

The IBMIM error (removed due to character limit):

```
./IBMIM
(IBMIM:22290): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(IBMIM:22290): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

...

(IBMIM:22289): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_line_count: assertion `layout != NULL' failed Floating point exception (core dumped)~
```

Adding `xlock`, `xmag`, and `ssh -v` output:

```
ssh -v root@<ip_address>
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to <ip_address> [<ip_address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA f6:69:0b:e8:73:a6:8e:5a:e5:de:95:96:cb:61:2e:4a
debug1: Host '<ip_address>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@<ip_address>'s password:
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to <ip_address> ([<ip_address>]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: No xauth program.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
Last login: Thu Mar 27 15:43:13 2014 from <build_machine_ip_address>
# xlock
-bash: xlock: command not found
# xmag
Error: Can't open display: localhost:12.0
```

Verification of `xauth` install and `PATH` (honestly I wasn't 100% that the below is sufficient, what is the difference between `xauth` and `xorg-x11-xauth`?, just need parent directory included in `PATH`?, etc):

```
[root@vm-ap01 apps]# yum whatprovides xauth
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
1:xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.2-7.1.el6.x86_64 : X.Org X11 X authority utilities
Repo        : myrepo
Matched from:
Other       : xauth



1:xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.2-7.1.el6.x86_64 : X.Org X11 X authority utilities
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: xauth



[root@vm-ap01 apps]# rpm -ql xauth
package xauth is not installed
[root@vm-ap01 apps]# rpm -ql xorg-x11-xauth
/usr/bin/mkxauth
/usr/bin/xauth
/usr/share/doc/xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.2
/usr/share/doc/xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.2/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.2/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.2/ChangeLog
/usr/share/doc/xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.2/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.2/README
/usr/share/man/man1/mkxauth.1x.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/xauth.1.gz
[root@vm-ap01 apps]# echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

I'm not exactly sure about "from the remote side", but below is the output when connected via `mobaxterm` from my workstation to RHEL box:

```
[root@vm-ap01 apps]# echo $DISPLAY
localhost:13.0
[root@vm-ap01 apps]# xauth list | awk '{print $1, $2}'
vm-ap01/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
vm-ap01/unix:11 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
vm-ap01/unix:12 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
vm-ap01/unix:13 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
vm-ap01/unix:14 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1

[root@vm-ap01 apps]# strace xclock
execve("/usr/bin/xclock", ["xclock"], [/* 34 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xc2b000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611d5000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99025, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99025, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f08611bc000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libXaw.so.7", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@|!\3601\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=412648, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x31f0200000, 2506392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x31f0200000
mprotect(0x31f025a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x31f0459000, 45056, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x59000) = 0x31f0459000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libXmu.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0pf`/:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=107600, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a2f600000, 2201280, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a2f600000
mprotect(0x3a2f618000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a2f818000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x3a2f818000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libXt.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p1\2418:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=412832, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611bb000
mmap(0x3a38a00000, 2508640, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a38a00000
mprotect(0x3a38a5f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a38c5e000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5e000) = 0x3a38c5e000
mmap(0x3a38c64000, 1888, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3a38c64000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\334\3412:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1300376, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a32e00000, 3394936, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a32e00000
mprotect(0x3a32f37000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a33137000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x137000) = 0x3a33137000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\30\3404:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=42472, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a34e00000, 2135176, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a34e00000
mprotect(0x3a34e09000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a35009000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9000) = 0x3a35009000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libXft.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320? ::\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=88632, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611ba000
mmap(0x3a3a200000, 2181216, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a3a200000
mprotect(0x3a3a214000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a3a414000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x3a3a414000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libxkbfile.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320J`\3601\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=151792, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x31f0600000, 2245768, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x31f0600000
mprotect(0x31f0623000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x31f0823000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x23000) = 0x31f0823000
mmap(0x31f0824000, 1160, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x31f0824000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p> 0:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=599384, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a30200000, 2633912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a30200000
mprotect(0x3a30283000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a30482000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x82000) = 0x3a30482000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\356!/:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1926800, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611b9000
mmap(0x3a2f200000, 3750152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a2f200000
mprotect(0x3a2f38b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a2f58a000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18a000) = 0x3a2f58a000
mmap(0x3a2f58f000, 18696, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3a2f58f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libXext.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3006 3:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=80944, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a33200000, 2174216, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a33200000
mprotect(0x3a33212000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a33412000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12000) = 0x3a33412000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libXpm.so.4", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`/\340\3571\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=72832, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x31efe00000, 2165496, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x31efe00000
mprotect(0x31efe11000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x31f0010000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10000) = 0x31f0010000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libSM.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\32`?:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=34024, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611b8000
mmap(0x3a3f600000, 2126776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a3f600000
mprotect(0x3a3f607000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a3f807000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x3a3f807000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libICE.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0pM`>:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=101608, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a3e600000, 2208960, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a3e600000
mprotect(0x3a3e617000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a3e817000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x3a3e817000
mmap(0x3a3e818000, 13504, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3a3e818000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\230`2:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=124728, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a32600000, 2217576, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a32600000
mprotect(0x3a3261d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a3281d000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1d000) = 0x3a3281d000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\r\340.:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=22536, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611b7000
mmap(0x3a2ee00000, 2109696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a2ee00000
mprotect(0x3a2ee02000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a2f002000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x3a2f002000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\\`4:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=223040, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a34600000, 2316776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a34600000
mprotect(0x3a34634000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a34834000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x34000) = 0x3a34834000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\310\2404:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=644912, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a34a00000, 2737840, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a34a00000
mprotect(0x3a34a98000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a34c97000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x97000) = 0x3a34c97000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611b6000
open("/lib64/libuuid.so.1", O_RDONLY)   = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\25 ;:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18936, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a3b200000, 2111272, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a3b200000
mprotect(0x3a3b204000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a3b403000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x3a3b403000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib64/libXau.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\r\2402:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=13168, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a32a00000, 2106112, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a32a00000
mprotect(0x3a32a02000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a32c02000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x3a32c02000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libexpat.so.1", O_RDONLY)  = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320<`3:\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=167648, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3a33600000, 2260432, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3a33600000
mprotect(0x3a33626000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3a33825000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x3a33825000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611b5000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611b4000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611b2000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f08611b2740) = 0
mprotect(0x3a30482000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3a2f58a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3a2f002000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3a2ec1f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f08611bc000, 99025)           = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99158576, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99158576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f085b321000
close(3)                                = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xc2b000
brk(0xc4c000)                           = 0xc4c000
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611d4000
read(3, "MemTotal:        1923456 kB\nMemF"..., 1024) = 1024
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f08611d4000, 4096)            = 0
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, 0)         = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=30849, groups=00000000}, [12]) = 0
sendto(3, "\24\0\0\0\26\0\1\3\320\3545S\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 20, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 20
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"0\0\0\0\24\0\2\0\320\3545S\201x\0\0\2\10\200\376\1\0\0\0\10\0\1\0\177\0\0\1"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 108
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"@\0\0\0\24\0\2\0\320\3545S\201x\0\0\n\200\200\376\1\0\0\0\24\0\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 128
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\24\0\0\0\3\0\2\0\320\3545S\201x\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\24\0\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 20
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1688, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611d4000
read(3, "#\n# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# An ex"..., 4096) = 1688
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f08611d4000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611d4000
read(3, "multi on\n", 4096)             = 9
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f08611d4000, 4096)            = 0
getpid()                                = 30849
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=355, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f08611d4000
read(3, "# Generated by NetworkManager\n\n\n"..., 4096) = 355
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f08611d4000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99025, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99025, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f08611bc000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/tls/x86_64/libnss_files,dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff58448b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/tls/libnss_files,dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib64/tls", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/lib64/x86_64/libnss_files,dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib64/x86_64", 0x7fff58448b00)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib64/libnss_files,dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64/libnss_files,dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff58448b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libnss_files,dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/tls", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/x86_64/libnss_files,dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/x86_64", 0x7fff58448b00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libnss_files,dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=69632, ...}) = 0
munmap(0x7f08611bc000, 99025)           = 0
open("/usr/lib64/X11/XtErrorDB", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getuid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
write(2, "Error: ", 7Error: )                  = 7
write(2, "Can't open display: localhost:13"..., 34Can't open display: localhost:13.0) = 34
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
exit_group(1)                           = ?
[root@vm-ap01 apps]#
```

Looks like SE Linux is enabled as well:

```
[root@vm-ap01 apps]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to run the install manager?

Comment: @JoelDavis I added it to the body of the question, but figured either way the `xterm` command should work as it does on the other VM...

Comment: Can you run other X11 programs, like `xlock` or `xmag`? If you run `ssh -v` instead of just `ssh`, does any message appear (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117159/cannot-start-xterm-over-ssh-after-several-successes/117369#117369)?

Comment: @Gilles can't run `xlock` or `xmag`. Ran `ssh -v`, but did not see the `“Rejected X11 connection after ForwardX11Timeout expired”` mentioned in the thread... If you have any thoughts I would love to know. Thank you for the response...!

Comment: Please use verbatim/code formatting for log transcripts (`{}` button or `Ctrl+K` or 4 space indents), not quote formatting which wraps lines. If my answer doesn't help, please post the output of `echo $DISPLAY; xauth list | awk '{print $1, $2}'` on the remote side. The output of `strace xclock` might help too. Is a security framework (presumably SELinux) active on the server? Does SSH X11 forwarding work if you log in to a non-root account?

Comment: @Gilles outputs have been added to the question body in case I've misinterpreted something. Unfortunately the `xauth` does already appear installed and included in `PATH`, as a note on the other RHEL VM where `xterm` does work and which served as a seed for this new one, the same `No xauth program` statement appears with `ssh -v` connection. In addition on both VMs the `sestatus` is identical. SSH X11 forwarding did not work with non-root although output was different: `user@vm-ap01 ~]$ xterm xterm Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:15.0`

Comment: @Gilles thank you again for the help and for the tip on the formatting for log transcripts (I think I did them properly this time...)

Comment: @Gilles something I noticed while comparing the `strace xclock` results between the working and non-working VMs was that they are looking in different locations for certain libraries: `open("/lib64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3` (working) vs `open("/lib64/tls/x86_64/libnss_files,dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` (not working). Is "tls" short for "thread local storage"? Is it possible that this is causing the problem, do you know how to reconfigure this on RHEL? (I could not find a clear answer with google)

Comment: Oh, nice find. Yes, [`tls` is for “thread-local storage”](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2005-08/msg00028.html), but that's irrelevant here. However the file name `libnss_files,dns.so.2` is wrong. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> debug1: No xauth program.
> ```

That looks like a problem. Make sure that you have the `xauth` program installed on both the server and the client. You're logging in as root, so make sure that `xauth` is in root's PATH, too. I'm not completely sure that this is the problem, because in my tests I found other error messages (“X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0”, appearing even without `-v`) if X11 forwarding wasn't working due to a lack of xauth, but this may be due to a version or configuration difference.

---

In the `strace xclock` output, you identified a line that doesn't match between a working machine and a non-working machine. On the non-working machine:

```
open("/lib64/tls/x86_64/libnss_files,dns.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

That file name is wrong: `libnss_files,dns.so.2` isn't supposed to exist, what exists is `libnss_files.so.2` and `libnss_dns.so.2`. These files are used by [NSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch), the component of the standard C library that manages sources for names of hosts, users, etc. Typical sources include `files` (`/etc/hosts`, `/etc/passwd`, …), [`dns`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), [`ldap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP), etc. You have a source called `files,dns` instead of a source called `files` and a source called `dns`. Edit the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and change the line(s) `SOMETHING: files,dns` to `SOMETHING: files dns`, i.e. the words must be whitespace-separated, not comma-separated.

I don't fully understand the trace but this is definitely wrong and could be causing your problem. In particular, I think that a wrong `hosts: …` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` might be causing your system not to find `localhost`.

Comment: It works now, I have *no* idea how the `nsswitch.conf` file was improperly updated like that... I can't thank you enough for your help!